# Django createview using primary key

Tags: django, forms, view

I have a model like this:

```
class Appointment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    engineer = models.ForeignKey(Engineer)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    age = models.IntegerField()
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.first_name
```

I have created a form using this model and I want to save it. Here I want the 'engineer' field to to be as the primary key is passed in the url.. like

```
engineer = Engineer.objects.get(pk=pk)
```

How can I do this. Or I should create a normal form and get its value via get method and assign to the field??

Comment: Do you have the `Engineer` model ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is a CreateView, you should build on the example [in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/) and add it in `form_valid`:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.engineer = Engineer.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
    return super(AppointmentCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: But its showing TypeError : 'int' object is not iterable  @DanielRoseman.